# How do i have multiple drops without coding everysingle one in maker function?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have been trying to get multiple drops to appear, but I can't seem to get them in unless I hard code every single one, because the canvas keeps refreshing with the drawover function, I was thinking to use an array, but I don't know how to apply that.

```js
var ALLOB = {
    speed: 3,
    recwidth: 5,
    recheight: 5,
    minvalue: 100,
    maxvalue: 900,
    lifetime: 10,
    xpos: 10,
    ypos: 10
};

function rand(min, max) {
    "use strict";
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var canvas = document.querySelector("#make");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function setCanvasWidth() {
    "use strict";
    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
setCanvasWidth();

function paintover() {
    'use strict';
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
function fall() {
    'use strict';
    ALLOB.ypos = ALLOB.ypos + ALLOB.speed;
    if (ALLOB.ypos > canvas.height - ALLOB.lifetime) {
        ALLOB.ypos = 10;
    }
}
function drawdrop(x, y) {
    'use strict';
    ctx.fillStyle = "#1cbc61";
    ctx.fillRect(ALLOB.xpos + x, ALLOB.ypos + y, ALLOB.recwidth, ALLOB.recheight);
       
}
function maker() {
    "use strict";
    drawdrop(400, 10);
}

function animate() {
    "use strict";
    paintover();
    maker();
    fall();
}

setInterval(animate, 30);
```

```css
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="make"></canvas>
```

Comment: Did you try to use an array of ALLOB objects each with varying xpos/ypos at least?

Comment: i did, but it creates random dots on the canvas. i watched a code pen by someone to make this as a learning project, but i dont understand how he made the array work. this is the link to the codepen http://codepen.io/jalabkhan/pen/bgNavG

Comment: See answers below. Basically your maker function should be generating the rain drops and storing them in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited maker to generate a 'drop' in random x/y positions.
These drop are added to ALLOB variable.

In the `paintover` func you loop through the `ALLOB` collection and draw each `drop` in the list.

I've also made the speed for each drop random for a nice effect :)

This should be a good starting point.

```js
var ALLOB = [];

function rand(min, max) {
  "use strict";
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function setCanvasWidth() {
  "use strict";
  ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

function paintover() {
  'use strict';
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ALLOB.forEach(function(droplet) {
    drawdrop(droplet);
  });
  window.requestAnimationFrame(paintover);
}

function fall(droplet) {
  'use strict';
  droplet.ypos += droplet.speed;
  if (droplet.ypos > canvas.height - droplet.lifetime) {
    droplet.ypos = 10;
  }
}

function drawdrop(droplet) {
  'use strict';
  ctx.fillStyle = "#1cbc61";
  ctx.fillRect(droplet.xpos, droplet.ypos, droplet.recwidth, droplet.recheight);
  fall(droplet)
}

function maker() {
  "use strict";
  ALLOB.push({
    speed: rand(1.5, 3.5),
    recwidth: 5,
    recheight: 5,
    minvalue: 100,
    maxvalue: 900,
    lifetime: 10,
    xpos: rand(-10, window.innerWidth + 10),
    ypos: rand(-10, window.innerHeight + 10)
  });

}

function animate() {
  "use strict";
  var maxDrops = 100;
  if (ALLOB.length < maxDrops) {
    window.setInterval(function() {
      if (ALLOB.length < maxDrops) {
        maker();
      }
    }, 30);
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(paintover);
}

var canvas = document.querySelector("#make");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
setCanvasWidth();

animate();
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="make"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

I helped clean up the code a little.  So you can use your `ALLOB` variable as type of template for a "drop class".  You can create an array of `ALLOB` variables, each created with different parameters.  I utilized the `rand` function that you had in there already to randomize the ALLOB parameters. Add the ALLOB variables to the array in a for loop.

Then the other parts of your code would work the same way, but you need to iterate through the array, and apply the drop changes to each instance of ALLOB.

```js
number_of_drops = 10;

var ALLOB_ARRAY = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < number_of_drops; i ++ ) {

    var ALLOB = {
      speed: rand(1,10),
      recwidth: 3,
      recheight: 3,
      lifetime: rand(5,15),
      xpos: rand(0,window.innerWidth),
      ypos: rand(0,window.innerHeight)
    };
  
  ALLOB_ARRAY.push(ALLOB)

}

function rand(min, max) {
    "use strict";
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var canvas = document.querySelector("#make");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function setCanvasWidth() {
    "use strict";
    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
setCanvasWidth();

function paintover() {
    'use strict';
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
function fall() {
    'use strict';
    for (var i = 0; i < ALLOB_ARRAY.length; i ++ ) {
      ALLOB_ARRAY[i].ypos = ALLOB_ARRAY[i].ypos + ALLOB_ARRAY[i].speed;
      if (ALLOB_ARRAY[i].ypos > canvas.height - ALLOB_ARRAY[i].lifetime) {
        ALLOB_ARRAY[i].ypos = 10;
      }
    }
}
function drawdrops() {
    'use strict';
    ctx.fillStyle = "#1cbc61";
    for (var i = 0; i < ALLOB_ARRAY.length; i ++ ) {
     ctx.fillRect(
       ALLOB_ARRAY[i].xpos, 
        ALLOB_ARRAY[i].ypos, 
        ALLOB_ARRAY[i].recwidth, 
        ALLOB_ARRAY[i].recheight
      );
    }
       
}

function animate() {
    "use strict";
    paintover();
    drawdrops();;
    fall();
}

setInterval(animate, 30);
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="make"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help...!!